# SQL Server - Why I cannot delete a specific record of my many-to-many table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

Consider the relationship:

[image]

I want to remove a row in my many-to-many (`userlabo`) table but SQL Server shows the following error:

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot delete last userlabo because usuario exists.
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

when running the statement:

```
delete from userlabo 
where iduser = 3 and idlabo = 3
```

Anyone has faced this problem before?

SQL Server only allows me to remove a row **if** a row in the `userlabo` table is not the last row with identity to be removed. This error only occurs for the highlighted line below:

```
idlabo    iduser
=================
     1         1 
     2         1 
     3         1 
     1         1 
     2         1 
     3         1 
     3         3 <-- this line cannot be removed, it gives the "Cannot delete last userlabo because usuario exists." error.
```

=== UPDATE ===

After reading @IngoB and @Jorge Campos comments, I realized that there is a trigger:

```
    .
    .
    .
    /* erwin Builtin Trigger */
    /* usuario  userlabo on child delete no action */
    /* ERWIN_RELATION:CHECKSUM="00026f13", PARENT_OWNER="", PARENT_TABLE="usuario"
    CHILD_OWNER="", CHILD_TABLE="userlabo"
    P2C_VERB_PHRASE="", C2P_VERB_PHRASE="", 
    FK_CONSTRAINT="R_23", FK_COLUMNS="iduser" */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted,usuario
      WHERE
        /* %JoinFKPK(deleted,usuario," = "," AND") */
        deleted.iduser = usuario.iduser AND
        NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM userlabo
          WHERE
            /* %JoinFKPK(userlabo,usuario," = "," AND") */
            userlabo.iduser = usuario.iduser
        )
    )
    BEGIN
      SELECT @errno  = 30010,
             @errmsg = 'Cannot delete last userlabo because usuario exists.'
      GOTO error
    END
    .
    .
    .
```

My tables were generated using erwin forward engineering and it probably embedded triggers to my tables without my knowledge. I think I have to take a careful look at the erwin physical model to figure out why it's embedding those triggers.

Bottom line: deleting the table's triggers solved the problem.

Comment: Can you show your table and constraints definition? If it is showing this error it means that your constraint is wrong defined. iduser in user is referencing iduser in userlabo and not the contrary

Comment: Show also the trigger which seems to be involved.

Comment: Indeed, there was a trigger that was created using erwin that was avoiding me to delete that record. Deleting the trigger solved the problem! Thanks!!